# How is recursion working in the following code?

Tags: java, recursion

```
void print (int n)
{
    if (n>0)
    {
        printf("hello");
        print(n-1);
    }
    printf("world");
}
```

In the code above, the **hello** is printed n times(which I get) and **world** is getting printed n+1 times(which I don't get at all). Shouldn't it print just for once, when the n=0? I mean its not returning anything to the calling function.
Thank You.

Comment: because `world` get´s printed even though it doesn´t print `hello` when the recursion stops.

Comment: I would recommend using a debugger to step through every line of the code, carefully looking at the stack all the time.

Comment: if you only want world to print just once, you need to have your method have `printf("world")` an else statement or just return after the `print()` call, this is because once it has finished printing all the `hello`s , the code then goes to the next line for each of the calls to `print()`

Comment: [Visualised Example](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#code=public+class+ClassNameHere+%7B%0A+++public+static+void+main(String%5B%5D+args)+%7B%0A+++++++print(3)%3B%0A++++++%0A+++%7D%0A+++%0A++++private+static+void+print+(int+n)+%7B%0A++++++++if+(n+%3E+0)+%7B%0A++++++++++++System.out.println(%22hello%22)%3B%0A++++++++++++print(n-1)%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++++++System.out.println(%22world%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D&mode=display&curInstr=0)

Comment: Keep at it! Recursion is a super hard topic in computer science. Even the best programmers have a hard time visualizing the call stack and output of recursive functions. Try and draw out your solution on paper, showing each call and print statement. It always helps to draw it out :)

Comment: Not that bad ques to be downvoted by someone. Most of us find recursion hard to visualize.

Comment: absolutely, some folks have just made stackoverflow a beginner repelling place.

Comment: @AnandTyagi Its not like that. Some people post questions without doing much work by themselves. Sometimes poor formatting also acts as magnet for downvotes.

Comment: @SauravSahu Fair point. Would you be able to answer one more of my question please? I'm done trying to solve this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440191/how-to-transform-a-string-such-that-it-only-contains-vowels-which-have-occurence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the hello is printed n times(which I get) and world is getting printed n+1 times(which I don't get at all).

This is how the instructions get executed in your case. "hello" gets executed for `[n, 1]` and  "world" gets executed for `[0, n]`.

```
n : printf("hello");
    n-1 : printf("hello");
          n-2 : printf("hello");
                ....
                    2 : printf("hello");
                        1 : printf("hello");
                            0 : printf("world");  << Difference is here
                        1 : printf("world");
                    2 : printf("world");    
                ....                            
          n-2 : printf("world");
    n-1 : printf("world");
n : printf("world");
```

Answer (score 4):

You are calling one function recursively, if there is no early return or any kind of condition every time that the print is called it will print "world". 

 To make it clear, if the printf("world); was inside an else it would print only once.

```
if (n>0)
{
  printf(“hello”);
  print(n-1);
}else{
  printf(“world”);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursion occurs when a function is defined within itself. In your function, every time `n > 0` you will `printf("hello");` and then call itself again with `n-1`. Remember that your function will keep making the call to itself and until  `n is equal to 0`. However in the last case when  `n is equal to 0`, the if statement will fail and continue to the last line in the method which is `printf("hello")`. As your method signature is void, this will cause the method to finish even though you have not specifically stated a return statement. When the method finishes, we recursively bubble up and finish the rest of each of the methods. In this case the rest of the method will be `printf("world")`, printing it once more than `printf("hello")`.